# SignalR client in Xamarin iOS app retrieves data from server but with missing properties

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, json.net, signalr

Hang tight, a lot of moving pieces to this... I have three different apps:

***Server***

***Web***

***iOS (through Xamarin)***

I am using SignalR to have each of the 2 clients (web, ios) communicate with the server. The web talks back and forth with the server perfectly. The iOS app talks too, but properties of objects are consistently missing.

**Problem Entity**: (*Name* returns perfectly, *Id* and *Status* come back as 0 and null, respectively)

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Response:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("people")]
    public IList<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Hub method:

```
public Response GetPlayers()
{
    return new Response
    {
        People = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person 1", Status = "In" },
            new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Person 2", Status = "Out" },
            new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Person 3", Status = "In" }
        }
    };
}
```

Xamarin iOS app:

```
await Hub.Start();
var peopleHubProxy = Hub.CreateHubProxy("PeopleHub");

Response response = await peopleHubProxy.Invoke<Response>("GetPlayers");

Console.WriteLine(response.People.Count); // Correct, returns 3 
Console.WriteLine(response.People[0].Name); // Correct, returns "Person 1"
Console.WriteLine(response.People[0].Id); // INCORRECT, returns 0
Console.WriteLine(response.People[0].Status); // INCORRECT, returns null

// Same goes for people 2 and 3
```

I turned the trace level to all, and I can see the JSON is coming through as expected:

```
OnMessage({"R":{"people":[{"id":1,"name":"Person 1","status":"In"},{"id":2,"name":"Person 2","status":"Out"},{"id":3,"name":"Person 3","status":"In"}]},"I":"0"})
```

In the web application, those properties are coming through just fine, so I know the problem is not server-side. What could be causing this on the iOS/Xamarin side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be that `Response` did not have a parameterless constructor, it was actually:

```
public Response(IList<Person> people)
{
    People = people;
}
```

Either Newtonsoft (Json.NET) or SignalR almost got the correct deserialization anyway, but something about it messed up a few of the `Person` properties... No clue how that could be, but adding a parameterless constructor fixed everything.

```
public Response() { }
```